# Authentication google in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail

I'm trying create authentication google in node js. But I have problem :

400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:3000/auth/gooogle/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to:

1. Log into https://console.developers.google.com
2. Click **Credentials** on the left side.
3. Click the name of your app under **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**.
4. Add http://localhost:3000/auth/gooogle/callback under the **Authorized redirect URIs** section and click **Save**.